# Dell Printer install

Tags: software-installation

Love Ubuntu but cannot get printer to work. It's a Dell 1130  laser printer.

I went to settings and tried to add printer and tried all various options but they alll jang for over an hour. Tried in both Gnome and KDE. Chose option to install openprint but it does not load, just hangs.

Loaded openprint fron software centre but doesnt seem to make any difference.

Comment: Is the specific model listed? If not you may need to install drivers from Dell. However, those are old (2012) and I'm not sure it installs correctly in newer Ubuntu releases.

Comment: Just checked and that model isn't natively supported. Please check the actual answer.

Comment: It would be nice if you could test it, give feedback and accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download and extract the [Dell drivers for 1130](http://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER00336428M/1/Dell1130_Linux_1.07.tar.gz)
2. `cd` to the extracted folder and run the installer: `sudo ./autorun`